# ASP.NET C# JQueryUI How to save index of accordion in a dynamically created user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui

ASP.NET C# JQueryUI How to save index of accordion in a dynamically created user control?

I have a JQueryUI accordion inside a user control , which is dynamically created n times (based on a chosen number inside a ComboBox) from the main aspx page. 
I have been using the following javascript code to save the index of accordions that occur once in the main aspx page, I have this once per accordion Control:

```
var activeAccordion1Item = document.getElementById("<%= HFaccordion1.ClientID %>");
var activeAccordion1 = 0;
if (activeAccordion1Item) {
    activeAccordion1 = parseInt(activeAccordion1Item.value);
}
$("#accordion1").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: "content",
    active: activeAccordion1,
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        var i = $("#accordion1").accordion("option", "active");
        var activeAccordion1Item = document.getElementById("<%= HFaccordion1.ClientID %>");
        activeAccordion1Item.value = i;
    }
});
```

And in aspx file:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HFaccordion1" runat="server" Value="0" />
```

I used this same approach for the one inside the user_control that can happen many times, and it also works, BUT the saved index is always the one from the first accordion, and that is shared among the rest. 
So, if I have index 2 in accordion1, and index 1 in accordion2, and a control causes postback, after the postback, both accordion1 and accordion2 appear with index 2 active.

How can I modify the above code to work for the dynamically created accordions independently of each other?

Answer (score 0):

You should change `$("#accordion1").accordion` to  `$(".acc").accordion`. `.acc` is class of accordions for this example. You used `$("#accordion1")` that this worked with active `accordion1`.

**Edit**

You need save active accordions in a array (`accordionsActivate`) when click on each accordion and for getting this array, store array in hidden field (`HFaccordions`) like this:

```
<script>
    var accordionsActivate = [];
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var $accordions = $(".acc").accordion({
            collapsible: true
                 , active: false
                 , icons: false

        }).on('click', function () {
            if ($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), accordionsActivate) < 0) {
                accordionsActivate.push($(this).attr('id'));
                $('#<%=this.HFaccordions.ClientID%>').val(accordionsActivate.join());
            }
            else {
                accordionsActivate.splice($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), accordionsActivate), 1);
                $('#<%=this.HFaccordions.ClientID%>').val(accordionsActivate.join());
            }

        });

        activeAccodions(); // Active accodions after postback
    });

    function activeAccodions() {
        if ($('#<%=this.HFaccordions.ClientID%>').val() === "")
            return;
        activeAccardions = $('#<%=this.HFaccordions.ClientID%>').val().split(',');
        for (var i = 0; i < activeAccardions.length; i++) {
            accordionsActivate.push(activeAccardions[i]);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < accordionsActivate.length; i++) {
            $('#' + accordionsActivate[i]).accordion("option", "active", 0);
        }
    }

</script>
```

**[Online demo (fiddle)](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ali_soltani/5kngkcht/3/)**

Comment: yes I did that so all accordions have the JqueyUI styling. BUT, I cannot do that in the activate function. So all accordions share one active index.

Comment: @user7792598 I created [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/d15qsemj/). Do you want to do this?

Comment: Hi Ali, that is not what I want to do. Your example includes no postbacks. I tried it on my web site, but after a postback, all accordions return to hidden. I need each different accordion to remember its index after a postback.

Comment: I tried it, but no luck. It has the same effect of the previous jsfiddle. After the postback, all accordions forget their active index.

Comment: @user7792598 I added `activeAccodions` for active accordions after postback. Please see this again.